# Rails3 Date import into database in wrong format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.9.2

I have an application that was working in ruby 1.8.7 When i switched to ruby 1.9.2 i can no longer import into my database.The date format seems to have changed, but i cant change my data, from mm/dd/yyyy. It seems ruby is using dd/mm/yyyy. I am importing data via csv that i can't change. I have tried run my original seed file with rake db:seed and have the same problem. How do i force the change so i can import dates in to my app.
The date format seems to have changed but i can change my data. from `mm/dd/yyyy`

it seems ruby is using `dd/mm/yyyy`

I am importing data via csv that i can't change.
I have tried run my original seed file with rake db:seed and have the same problem.

i Need force the change so i can import dates in to my app.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to import the CSV?

Comment: listit = "000076.TXT"
CSV.foreach(listit, {:headers => true, :col_sep => "|", :force_quotes => true, :quote_char => "~"}) do |row|
@contracts = Contract.find_or_create_by_unique3(row[0])
@contracts.update_attributes({ 
:unique3             =>  row[0],
:prntkey23             =>  row[1],
:prntkey13         =>  row[2],
:act_code            =>  row[3],
:agent       => row[7],
:act_booked => row[8],
:contract_number    => row[28],
:type_of_event    => row[63],
:date_of_event    => row[67],
:first_name    => row[68],
:last_name    => row[69] }) 
 end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
:date_of_event => Date.strptime(row[67], "%m/%d/%Y").to_s(:db)
```

`.strptime` parses the date, then `.to_s(:db)` converts it into a database-friendly format.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and it worked. perfectly. But is there a way to set this in rails now or do we always have to add strptime.